# How to create a Multiline text box in property grid .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to create a multi-line text box in propertygrid control in Visual studio but can't seem to find a way to do it in .Net6. We used to be able to do this in .net framework using the System.Design.dll like below

[Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]

this dll does not seem to be available in .net6.
Could someone point me to how this is cab be done when developing in .Net6

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `System.Windows.Forms.Design.dll` and `System.Windows.Forms.dll`

You can find them at `dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\6.0.4\`

Comment: Thanks, have added the files and now working.